# Display Firebase data appended with jquery to a table in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to append data through I pull from Firebase to a table in the order of newest to oldest posts.  I currently have the following setup in my code base (simplified to address issue):

```
var theDataRef = new Firebase('https://my-app.firebaseio.com');

theDataRef.orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(25).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    displaytableRow(message.name, message.text);
}

function displaytableRow(name, message) {

    $("#sch").find('tbody > tr:first')
            .before($("<tr><td><div>" + name + ":" + message + "</div></td></tr>"))
};
```

I have tried to create a table that displays newest to oldest data by using both firebase and jquery techniques but every time my data is displayed in a random order.  I have a working timestamp field on every record in my data as well but even ordering by that does not solve the problem.  Has anybody had any experience building this successfully?

EDIT:

The timestamp is gotten with the following code:

```
var timestamp = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

And the database architecture is structured like so:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code that you used to order by the timestamp, as well as your database structure?

Comment: Updated per your requests

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order your posts from newest to oldest you can do the following:

1/ Store a field in your post that is the inverse of the TimeStamp as follows:

```
var tDate = new Date().getTime();
var postData = {
    //.....  
    timestampInverted: (0 - tDate),
    //.....
};
```

2/ Query your posts ordered by this field as follows:

```
theDataRef.orderByChild("timestampInverted").limitToLast(25).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    displaytableRow(childSnapshot.val().name, childSnapshot.val().text);
  });
});
```

It is important to note that `theDataRef.orderByChild("timestampInverted").limitToLast(25)` returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query), which returns a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) : Therefore you need to use `snapshot.forEach()` (see doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach)) to iterate over the different posts items.

Also note that "even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you always need to loop over the `snapshot`".

Comment: So this is weird, that method works on web simulators but is not working properly on a device, they are still in a random order

Comment: Could you precise what is a “web simulator” and what is your device? Isn’t your front end a web browser?